# Hello World in WSO2 esb

Tags: wso2-esb

To start with WSO2 esb,I need to develop "Hello World" sample where in "getGreeting" operation will have input variable of person's name and a standard response like "Hello (person Name) " will be returned.

Thanks
Amit Pawar.

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look at https://docs.wso2.org/display/ESB481 : you will find tutorials and samples that will help you to achieve your goal